# next/image not working with props as image source

Tags: reactjs, next.js, strapi, nextjs-image

My `Home` page sends data from my `strapi` cms to my `PostSlider` component via `props`

```
import React from "react";
import styles from './index.module.scss'
import { AxiosService } from '../utils/axios-service'
import PostSlider from '../components/postSlider/postSlider'

const Home = ({ posts }) => {
  return (
    <div id='contentsWrap' className={styles.dohandsWrap}>
      <PostSlider home={true} posts={posts} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const axios = AxiosService.create()
  const res = await axios.get('/archives', {
    params: {
      category: 'news',
      display: true,
      showDoson: true,
      _limit: 5,
      _sort: 'id:DESC'
    }
  })

  return {
    props: {
      posts: res.data,
    },
  }
}
```

My postSlider component then maps over the data to fill my slider

```
import React from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
import styles from './postSlider.module.scss'
import Link from 'next/link'
import Image from 'next/image'

export default function PostSlider({ home, posts }) {
  var settings = {
    infinite: posts.length > 2 ? true : false,
    autoplay: false,
    speed: 500,
    autoplaySpeed: 3000,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
  };
  return (
    <section className={`${styles.postSlider} postSlider ${home ? styles.postSliderHome : 'postSliderNotHome'} ${posts.length > 2 ? 'postSliderPadding' : ''}`}>
      <Slider {...settings}>
        {posts.map((post) => {
          const date = new Date(post.displayDate);
          return (
            <Link key={post.id} href={`/news/${post.id}`}>
              <a className={styles.postSliderLink}>
                <article>
                  <Image src={post.images[0]?.url} alt={post.images[0]?.alternativeText} width={376} height={190} layout="fixed" />
                </article>
              </a>
            </Link>
          )
        })}
      </Slider>
    </section>
  );
}
```

I made sure to include my cdn address in `module.exports` in `next.config.js` but I get the following error

> Error: Image is missing required "src" property. Make sure you pass
> "src" in props to the `next/image` component. Received:
> {"width":376,"height":190}

[image: error]

If I remove the `next/image` component for the normal `img` tag, everything works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, it seems that one of your posts has an empty `images` array?

`Image` component is required to have `src` property and you pass `undefined` instead.

You can check if there is at least one image and then render it, like that:

```
<article>
  {post.images.length > 0 && (
    <Image src={post.images[0].url} alt={post.images[0].alternativeText} width={376} height={190} layout="fixed" />
  )}
</article>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case giving image conditinally solved the problem

```
<Image  src={cartItem?.image ? cartItem.image: "/images/default_product.png" } alt={cartItem.name}  height="40"
            width="120"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try before the return:

```
const src = {src: post.images[0]?.url}
```

Then inside the return:

```
<Image {...src}    //etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the `<Image />` tag doesn't work like it should and doesn't accept the ***src*** .  Try defining the URL before return and then pass the URL in the ***src*** property.

Just before return:

```js
const url = post.images[0]?.url;
```

And then you can add:

```html
<Image src={url} alt={post.images[0]?.alternativeText} width={376} height={190} layout="fixed" />
```