# Error: Image is missing required "src" property. Make sure you pass "src" in props to the `next/image` There is no problem when I use 'ımg'

Tags: next.js, sanity, next-images, next-link

**product.jsx**
There is no problem when I use **ımg** but I want to use **Next/image**
and my old code was **link**, I edited it as **nextLink**

```
import React from 'react'
import NextLink from 'next/link'
import { urlFor } from '../lib/client'
import Image from 'next/image'

const Product = ({ product: { image, name, slug, price } }) => {
  return (
    <div>
    <NextLink href={`/product/${slug.current}`} passHref>
    <div className="product-card">
    <Image
            src={urlFor(image && image[0])}
            alt={name}
            width={250}
            height={250}
            className="product-image"
          />
          <p className="product-name">{name}</p>
          <p className="product-price">${price}</p>
    </div>
    </NextLink>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Product
```

**[slug.js]**

I can't figure out why the problem is

```
 <div className="product-detail-container">
        <div>
          <div className="image-container">
            < Image src={urlFor(image && image[index])} className="product-detail- 
           image" />
          </div>
          <div className="small-images-container">
            {image?.map((item, i) => (
              <Image
                key={i}
                src={urlFor(item)}
                alt={name}
                className={i === index ? 'small-image selected-image' : 'small- 
                image'}
                onMouseEnter={() => setIndex(i)}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
```

**next.config.js**
i am using sanity i added it here to next config file

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
}
module.exports = nextConfig,
{
  images:{
    domains: ['cdn.sanity.io'],
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [next/image not working with props as image source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66131622/next-image-not-working-with-props-as-image-source) You can't pass undefined as src, you need to check that the image src actually exists and only then render Image component.